# Spring Boot and Integration Help Getting Started

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-boot, mqtt

I have been playing around with Spring Boot and Spring Integration and I am having a little bit of trouble getting started.

I would like to build an application that I can deploy to multiple servers, inter-communicating over rabbitmq and mqtt.  I would like to have each server on startup broadcast their presence. A server should always be acting as master/director/etc, and respond that that server is the master, where the receiving server should be taking direction.

1. application starts and broadcasts presence

   - waits for response from current master
2. current master responds to server broadcasts
3. application keeps polling for master availability

If master goes away

1. application broadcast fails to get response from master
2. application assumes role of master

   - if another application has already assumed role of master, application records who the new master is

I have been going through spring integration sample code, but just struggling find a starting point.  I appreciate any input.

Thank you for the help while I learn Spring Integration

Comment: In terms of starting points, are you trying to work out how to do pub/sub over Rabbit MQ? In which case there's this: http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/ Or is this just about how to manage which server is currently in control?

Comment: @Steve I, more or less, am trying to learn more about spring integration and boot.  I know that in the near future I will have number of interactions that I will need to make similar to this.  I thought something like this would be a good way to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing currently built in to do what you want.

We did put something together a couple of years ago for [Spring One](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-ha-demo). But that code needs to be brought up to date to work with the current framework.

We are looking to put something together later this year, probably using [Spring XD](http://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/) which uses zookeeper for leader election and managing deployments.

Comment: thank you for your response.  I will have to add Spring XD into the mix as well.  And thank you for putting the correct terms in there.  I figured there had to be a model that was already using this.  So for right now, I am just trying to learn more about Spring Integration, Boot and messaging.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether [this example code](http://github.com/andypiper/spring-int-mqtt) will help you, but since you mention Boot, Integration and MQTT... just a simple demo, and obviously it would need to be adapted for your use case.